# No result getting from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started to learn Android Studio, and I am trying to make a search activity that can search for a data from my firebase database. But whenever I try to search no result shows up on the screen and does not retrieve any data from the database. Can anyone solve the problem? Thanks.

```java
private void searchForMatch(final String keyword) {
        Log.d(TAG, "searchForMatch: searching for a match: " + keyword);
        imageDTOs.clear();
        if(keyword.length() == 0) {

        } else {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = reference.child("books").orderByChild("title").equalTo(keyword);

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found book:" + singleSnapshot.getValue(ImageDTO.class).toString());

                        imageDTOs.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(ImageDTO.class));

                        }

                        searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this, R.layout.item_library, imageDTOs);
                        listView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                    }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

[image: firebase database]

Comment: is your internet permission set on your android manifest ?

Comment: yes it's already set

Comment: what about database rules, are set to public ?

Comment: First things is to stop ignoring possible errors. The minimum `onCancelled` looks like this: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: yes the database rules are set to public

Comment: I have added it but still not working